# Drawing MKPolyline to be more accurate

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

So I am creating an app to track a user's running routes. I am to show a polyline that represents where a user has ran, between a start annotation that is dropped when user begins and a end annotation that is dropped when user clicks a finish button. Seeing as how someone can run pretty much anywhere, is there a way to draw a polyline that is Not limited to just main roads and streets? For example if someone runs somewhere that does not have main roads/streets, how would I show the polyline going through that area on the map? (See Image) Or is that not even possible in swift? [image]

In addition, is it possible to fix these gaps?
[image]

Here is my code for rendering the polyline:

```
func drawPolyline() {
   guard let startingCoordinate = self.startingCoordinate, let endingCoordinate = self.endingCoordinate else { return }
   let request = MKDirections.Request()
   request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: startingCoordinate))
   request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: endingCoordinate))
   request.transportType = .walking
        
   let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
   directions.calculate { [weak self] (response, error) in
      guard let self = self else { return }
      guard error == nil else { return }
      guard response != nil else { return }
            
      if let route = response?.routes.first {
         self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
         self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15), animated: true)
      }
    }
  }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
   let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay               
   renderer.strokeColor = .systemBlue
   renderer.lineWidth = 3
   return renderer
}

// code to get coordinate for annotations
guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
let annotation = MapAnnotation(title: title, coordinate: coordinate) 
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: you're not drawing where you runner has been - you're drawing the directions between start and finish.  Don't lookup placemarks - just create an array of locations (not just start and finish) and create a line joining them - it will show the actual route (or as accurately as it was measured)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an updated location every time it changes, and you can either build up an array of locations, or store them in a database for later retrieval.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    // the last location presented here is the current position of the runner
    self.locations.append(locations.last)
    // store this in a database, or as a class variable
    
}
```

You can set the desired accuracy when you initialise your location manager

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

and then when you're creating the map, create a line showing the runner's route

```
let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: self.locations, count: self.locations.count)
self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
```

Here's an example of the output - looks like the finish is in the middle of the run, but that's because I was heading back home
[image]

Comment: Hello! That worked great. Do you know if there is any way to show curves, since a runner doesn't always just run straight? Currently it is just streamlining from start annotation to end annotation.

Comment: if you use kCLLocationAccuracyBest you should get updated locations every 1 or 2 metres, and you will get a lot more than just start and finish.  You may need to create your own array of locations  - I will update the answer with a solution that I used recently on a bike tracking app

Comment: cool, happy to help, and handy that your requirement matched something I had done recently :-)